# Spring reactor rsocket connection limits

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-rsocket

I'm managing socket client using spring integration TCP and try to use RSocket.
My target server has connections limit so I need like `max-connections`.
Would RSocket support this?

If It's not support, am i using `rate-limit(third part lib)`?